# Rerofit2 post error when I send DTO by FormUrlEncoded

Tags: android, post, retrofit2

I occur error as '@Body parameters cannot be used with form or multi-part encoding' When I send the DTO by FormUrlEncoded
naturally when I remove the @FormUrlEncoded than it doesn't occur error
But My server construct for FormUrlEncoded

So I want to send the DTO by FormUrlEncoded, What should I do?

RestAPI.java

```
public interface RestAPI {
    interface Join {
        @FormUrlEncoded
        @POST("/api/users")
        Call<Res> createTask(@Body User user);
    }
    Retrofit RETROFIT = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(Config.ServerUrl).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
}


public class User {
String username;
String password;


public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
}
```

Res.java

```
public class Res {

private Boolean response;
private String msg;

public Boolean getResponse() {
    return response;
}

public void setResponse(Boolean response) {
    this.response = response;
}

public String getMsg() {
    return msg;
}

public void setMsg(String msg) {
    this.msg = msg;
}
}
```

Main.java

```
user = new User();
user.setUsername("TEST");
user.setPassword("1234");
    RestAPI.Join join = RestAPI.RETROFIT.create(RestAPI.Join.class);
    Call<Res> resCall = join.createTask(user);
    resCall.enqueue(new Callback<Res>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<Res> call, Response<Res> response) {
    System.out.println(response.body().getResponse());
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<Res> call, Throwable t) {

    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Retrofit like this:

**RetrofitAPI.class**

```
public interface RetrofitAPI
{
    @POST("/your/server/doSomething")
    Call<ReturnData> doSomething(@Body Param param);
}
```

**ServiceGenerator.class**

```
private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
private static RetrofitAPI retrofitAPI = null;
private static Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(Constant.BASE_URL).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

public static Retrofit getRetrofit()
{
    if(retrofit == null)
        retrofit = builder.client(httpClient.build()).build();
    return retrofit;
}
private static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
    return getRetrofit().create(serviceClass);
}
public static RetrofitAPI getRetrofitAPI()
{
    if(retrofitAPI == null)
        retrofitAPI = createService(RetrofitAPI.class);
    return retrofitAPI;
}
```

**Actual code**

```
public static void doSomethingViaServer(Param param, Callback<ReturnData> callback)
{
    if(param == null)
        return;

    RetrofitAPI api = ServiceGenerator.getRetrofitAPI();
    Call<ReturnData> call = api.doSomething(param);
    call.enqueue(callback);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thansk, I solved the problem, server problem, server input code 'app.use(bodyParser())' so Server could it get post form-data, that's it, but I spent a lot of time